# Using libavformat in C code, undefined x86_64 symbols

Tags: c, macos, libav, libavformat

I am working on a project where I have to create a simple C program that makes use of `libavformat` to convert a file from one format to another.

I am working on OS X (10.8.3) and have installed `libav` through the following steps.

First, install dependancies using Homebrew:

```
brew install yasm zlib faac lame speex libogg libvorbis theora libvpx x264
XviD openjpeg opencore-amr freetype
```

Next, download libav from here: http://libav.org/download.html (using the `libav 9 "plain 9"` release)

Finally, configure with the following commands:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.1/include/openjpeg-1.5/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/lame/3.99.5/include/lame/"

./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-version3
--enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-nonfree
--enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis
--enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfreetype
--enable-doc --enable-gnutls --enable-shared --arch=x86_64
```

Everything compiles correctly and gives a list of supported codecs, encoders, decoders, muxers, demuxers, etc.

I then run `make && sudo make install`.

However, once I try to make use of `av_register_all()` and some other critical functions in my own C code, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_av_register_all", referenced from:
      _main in base-bPKLay.o
```

I have tried compiling it using `gcc -Wall base.c -o base` as well as `clang -Wall base.c -o base`, but both give the above error. I fear that something is wrong with how the libraries are linked, but I am not experienced enough with C programming in general to know where to look next. The C code itself compiles fine when I remove the `av_register_all()` call.

The include for libavformat looks like this: `#include "libavformat/avformat.h"`

Any help is appreciated. I have tried adding `-arch x86_64` to the CFLAGS export, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined symbols error occur because you do not tell the linker to link against libav.

Try using `gcc -Wall -o base -lav base.c`. The `-l` flag tells the linker to use the libav library.

Note that the *lib* part is left out when using the `-l` flag!

Comment: That did it, cheers! Needed -lavformat (and some others later, but it was obvious once I figured out the pattern).